# Giving 360 degrees series of images of an object as an input, is it possable to generate 3d model from this?

Tags: 3d, cloud, point

As title says, I want to generate a 3d model from a set of 360 images of an object.
I have no idea where to begin - I saw that the basic thing to do is generate all the 3D points of the model(called "point cloud" as I understand), how do I do that?

I found some PDF documents which shows some ways to do it, but they just throw a bunch of equations, and the idea in a general.

Does someone can direct me to material in the subject, I saw in Utube a man imputing 2 pictures of him self and generates the 3d points (textured model in the end) - nothing too fancy and have been done...

Thank you for your patience and for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

search for stereoscopy

main idea is this:

1. take 2 pictures of the same view from 2 known locations
2. find points of interests on both pictures
3. triangulate 3d position of coresponding points relative to cameras

... and you have 3d coordinates in pictures...

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible using stereoscopy. The idea is to take two images taken from slightly different angles and generate depth values for the overlapping pixels. The depth value then helps create the point cloud. In your case, this can be done for each neighboring image pair (e.g. Image1 & Image2, then Image2 & Image3, etc.) and then resulting point clouds can be combined together into one to generate the final 3D model.

While possible, it is a very tricky and complex process. There are a great deal of details at work (e.g. the images must be aligned perfectly, then stretched to invert the perspective distortion, you need the focal distance of the lens for each image, etc.) and the results I have seen are not very satisfying, having a lot of noise, especially when the scene is feature-less, making it hard for the algorithm to detect similarities.

Take a look at Middlebury (http://vision.middlebury.edu/), it's an evaluation of some stereo vision algorithms, one of the most well known projects in this field. It should direct you to lots of papers and resources. The tool I've seen my colleagues use is the OpenCV framework.